# How to put two fields of database to one combobox in vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Private Sub ForgotPasswordPage1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim table2 As New DataTable
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim da2 As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim con = New MySqlConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;password=;database=pharma"
    Try
        'we open Connection
        con.Open()

        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT `security_question_1` from pharma.account_admin where `u_name`='" & Login.u_name.Text & "';"
        End With

        'declare dt as new datatable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
          Dim dt2 As New DataTable
        With sq
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            'it fills the da values into dt
            da.Fill(dt)
            'dt provides the data surce of combobox
            .DataSource = dt
            'specify the what to display
            .DisplayMember = "security_question_1"

            'and the value
            .ValueMember = "security_question_1"

        End With


        With cmd1
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT `security_question_2` from pharma.account_admin where `u_name`='" & Login.u_name.Text & "';"
        End With
        With sq
            da.SelectCommand = cmd1
            'it fills the da values into dt
            da.Fill(dt)
            'dt provides the data surce of combobox
            .DataSource = dt
            'specify the what to display
            .DisplayMember = "security_question_2"

            'and the value
            .ValueMember = "security_question_2"

        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
```

Here's my code. I want to have security question 1 and security question 2, which are two different fields in my database to be inserted in a combobox.

Comment: That seems an odd thing to want to do based on that data but it's not possible with the standard `ComboBox` control anyway.  You can either manipulate the data so that the two columns are combined into one value or else you can use a custom control. If you want to go the latter route, a web search for ".net multicolumn combobox" should turn up some options. It always has in the past when others have requested something similar.

Comment: Is there any way I can do the first choice with just coding in vb?

Comment: Of course there is. What else would you do either option in other than VB code?

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing in my code is the use of Parameters. This change will help protect your database from malicious input. I also used an alias for security question 1 and 2. (the As Question in the select command.) Double check the data type of User Name. I guessed at varchar but it could be something else. Change the MySalDbType accordingly. Using DataTable.Load adds the records from the second query to the data table. Actually, I think the two select could be run as a Union. If you are only getting 2 questions back then I would select both questions in one query, use a datareader and add the values to the combo box manually. The Using/End Using statements ensure that objects that implement IDisosable can release their unmanaged resources as soon as posible.

```
Using cmd As New MySqlCommand
            Using da As New MySqlDataAdapter
                Using con = New MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;password=;database=pharma")
                    Try
                        With cmd
                            .Connection = con
                            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                            .CommandText = "SELECT `security_question_1` As Question from pharma.account_admin where `u_name`= @UserName;"
                            .Parameters.Add("@UserName", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Login.u_name.Text
                        End With
                        Using dt As New DataTable
                            da.SelectCommand = cmd
                            da.Fill(dt)
                            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT `security_question_2` As Question from pharma.account_admin where `u_name`= @UserName;"
                            con.Open()
                            Using dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                                dt.Load(dr)
                                con.Close()
                                ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
                                ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Question"
                                ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Question"
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```